# Docker: /etc/hosts not automatically updated on source container restart

Tags: docker

Let's say that I have:

- a `pg_db` container

  ```
  docker run -d --name pg_db postgres
  ```
- a `web` container, linked to the `pg_db` container

  ```
  docker run -d --name web --link pg_db:db my-web-app
  ```

In the `web` container, I can access to the `pg_db` via the `/etc/hosts` name resolution.

```
# cat /etc/hosts
...
172.17.0.17    db
```

But if I restart the `pg_db` container, it has a new IP address, and the **[documentation](https://docs.docker.com/userguide/dockerlinks/#updating-the-etchosts-file)** says that **the linked containers should have their `/etc/hosts` file automatically updated, but it is not my case.**

```
$ docker restart pg_db
$ docker inspect --format '{{.NetworkSettings.IPAddress}}' pg_db
172.17.0.21
```

And in the still running `web` container:

```
# cat /etc/hosts
...
172.17.0.17    db        <-- No change!!!
```

- Is it a **bug**?
- Or is it the **new Docker behavior**, and thus the **documentation is out-dated** on this point?

---

```
$ docker info
Containers: 5
Images: 67
Storage Driver: aufs
 Root Dir: /var/lib/docker/aufs
 Dirs: 77
Execution Driver: native-0.2
Kernel Version: 3.13.0-24-generic
Operating System: Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

$ docker version
Client version: 1.3.0
Client API version: 1.15
Go version (client): go1.3.3
Git commit (client): c78088f
OS/Arch (client): linux/amd64
Server version: 1.3.0
Server API version: 1.15
Go version (server): go1.3.3
Git commit (server): c78088f
```

Comment: I don't know why you were downvoted, this is a well-asked question.

Comment: I think the [more] accepted way to get the IP Address of the db container is by way of ENV Vars.  DB_HOST_PORT_ADDRESS and DB_HOST_PORT (iirc).  Realize the first part (DB) is the NAME of the container.  I think [this link](https://docs.docker.com/reference/run/#env-environment-variables) might be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You also have to restart the web container to pickup the change.